# Oracle SQL Query - Finding the count of tuples that have the same attribute value within same table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
PURCHASENO  NUMBER(5),
RECEIPTNO   NUMBER(6) );
```

Question:  Write a SQL statement to count the number of purchases for which there have been at least 10 other purchases issued from the same first 3 digits of `receiptNo`.

**My Code (ATM)**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PURCHASE
WHERE SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3) IN (
  SELECT SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3)
  FROM PURCHASE
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3)
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10);
```

I was wandering if anyone could think of a query for this question not using `GROUP BY` OR `JOINS`. (Pretty much i wanna try and make an inefficient query to show the power of indexes, but at the moment my query speed for the code that I have is already at `00:00:00.01` so it's hard for me to show it)

Answer (score 0):

without using join and group by, this is what i came up, using `row_number()` to generate unique rows by `PURCHASE.RECEIPTNO`.

```
select count(distinct receipt_no) from (
select row_number() over (partition by SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3) order by message) rn
     , SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3)  as receipt_no
from PURCHASE)
where rn >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

By using below query you can reduce the number of SUSTR function calls.

```
select * from (
  with A as
  (select SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3) aa from purchase)
   select count(*) cc from A
  group by aa
  )
where cc > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(COND_MET) AS RESULT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(1) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 0, 3)
                ) > 10 THEN 1
            END AS COND_MET
        FROM
            PURCHASE
    );
```

Cheers!!